# Guess the Number game, number of guesses left labels not updating

Tags: java

I have a gui guess the number game, basically the user can choose between three difficulty levels, easy,intermediate and hard, each has its own number of guesses, easy has 15, intermediate has 10 and hard 5. The user can use a peek button which will display the random number for 3 seconds but will deduct a point from the number of guesses. The problem I'm having is that the number of guesses label is not decrementing when a wrong guess is entered. Here is the code.

```
public class Gui {

    private static final int WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 300;
    private static final int X_COORDINATE = 400;
    private static final int Y_COORDINATE = 200;
    public static void main(String[]args){
        GuessTheNumber g = new GuessTheNumber();
        g.setBounds(X_COORDINATE,Y_COORDINATE,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        g.setVisible(true);
        
    }
    
}

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GuessTheNumber extends JFrame{

    private Random random = new Random();
    private final int EASY_GAME_MODE  = 15;
    private final int INTERMEDIATE_GAME_MODE = 10;
    private final int HARD_GAME_MODE = 5;
    private final int BUTTON_1 = 1;
    private final int BUTTON_2 = 2;
    private final int BUTTON_3 = 3;
    private final int WIDTH = 300;
    private final int HEIGHT = 30;
    private  final int Y = 10;
    private final int X = 120;

    private int userGuess;
    private int level;
    private int randomNumber;
    private int turns;
    private int playAgain;
    private int buttonId;

    private final JFrame f = new JFrame();

    private final JLabel l1;
    private final JLabel l2 = new JLabel();
    private final JLabel l3 = new JLabel();
    private final JLabel l4 = new JLabel();
    private final JLabel l5 = new JLabel();
    private final JLabel l6 = new JLabel();
    private final JLabel l7 = new JLabel();

    private final JButton b1;
    private final JButton b2;
    private final JButton b3;
    private final JButton b4;
    private final JButton b5;
    private final JButton b6;

    private final Timer peekTimer;

    private final JTextField t1;

    public GuessTheNumber(){
        displayRandomNumber();
        setLayout(null);
        setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        t1 = new JTextField(60);
        l1 = new JLabel("Guess The Number");
        l1.setFont(new Font("Times new Roman",Font.BOLD,30));
        l1.setForeground(getForeGround());
        l2.setForeground(getForeGround());

        l1.setBounds(X,Y,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        l2.setBounds(270,60,120,30);
        l3.setBounds(140,100,120,30);
        l4.setBounds(270,100,120,30);
        l5.setBounds(390,100,120,30);
        l6.setBounds(100,130,120,30);
        l7.setBounds(220,130,120,30);
        t1.setBounds(10,50,90,30);

        add(l1);
        add(l2);
        add(l3);
        add(l4);
        add(l5);
        add(l6);
        add(l7);
        add(t1);

        b1 = new JButton("Submit");
        b2 = new JButton("Easy");
        b3 = new JButton("Intermediate");
        b4 = new JButton("Hard");
        b5 = new JButton("Reset");
        b6 = new JButton("Peek");

        b1.setBounds(10,90,90,30);
        b2.setBounds(110,50,90,30);
        b3.setBounds(220,50,110,30);
        b4.setBounds(350,50,90,30);
        b5.setBounds(10,170,90,30);
        b6.setBounds(10,130,90,30);

        add(b1);
        add(b2);
        add(b3);
        add(b4);
        add(b5);
        add(b6);

        b6.setEnabled(false);

       peekTimer = new Timer(3000, new ActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               l6.setText("");
               peekTimer.stop();
           }
       });
       peekTimer.setRepeats(false);

        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                startingPoint(e);
            }
        });

        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                turns = setGameDifficulty(e);
                turns = level;
            }
        });

        b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                turns = setGameDifficulty(e);
                turns = level;

            }
        });

        b4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                turns = setGameDifficulty(e);
                turns = level;
            }
        });

        b5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                resetFields();
            }
        });

        b6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                peeks(e);
                b6.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
    }

    private void startingPoint(ActionEvent e){
        if(!isInputEmpty()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,"FIELD CANNOT BE EMPTY!");
        }else if(!isGuessValidNumber()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,"INVALID INPUT! NUMBERS ONLY!");
        }else if(!isNumberOutOfBounds()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f," INVALID NUMBER " + t1.getText() + " IS NOT IN RANGE! ");
        }else{
            checkGuess(l5);
           // checkChoice(e);
        }
    }

    private int setGameDifficulty(ActionEvent e){
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if(source == b2){
            buttonId = BUTTON_1;
        }else if(source == b3){
            buttonId = BUTTON_2;
        }else if(source == b4){
            buttonId = BUTTON_3;
        }else{
            buttonId = 0;
        }
        turns = processButton();
        lockInDifficulty();
        return buttonId;
    }

    private int processButton(){
        switch (buttonId) {
            case BUTTON_1 -> {
                level = EASY_GAME_MODE;
                printOutNumberOfTurns(EASY_GAME_MODE, l3);
            }
            case BUTTON_2 -> {
                level = INTERMEDIATE_GAME_MODE;
                printOutNumberOfTurns(INTERMEDIATE_GAME_MODE, l4);
            }
            case BUTTON_3 -> {
                level = HARD_GAME_MODE;
                printOutNumberOfTurns(HARD_GAME_MODE, l5);
            }
            default -> System.out.println("UNEXPECTED ERROR!");
        }
        return buttonId;
    }

    private void lockInDifficulty(){
        b2.setEnabled(false);
        b3.setEnabled(false);
        b4.setEnabled(false);
        b6.setEnabled(true);
    }

    private void printOutNumberOfTurns(int numberOfTurns,JLabel label){
        label.setText("" + numberOfTurns);
    }

    private void displayRandomNumber(){
        randomNumber = getRandomNumber();
    }

    private int getRandomNumber(){
        return (int)(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
    }

    private void peeks(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() == b6 && turns == EASY_GAME_MODE){
            peek(l3);
        }else if(e.getSource() == b6 && turns == INTERMEDIATE_GAME_MODE){
            peek(l4);
        }else if(e.getSource() == b6 && turns == HARD_GAME_MODE){
            peek(l5);
        }
    }

    private int peek(JLabel label){
        l6.setText(String.valueOf(randomNumber));
        level--;
        label.setText("" + level);
        System.out.println("Turns: " + level);
        System.out.println("Random Number: " + randomNumber);
        checkTurns();
        peekTimer.start();
        return level;
    }

     private void checkChoice(ActionEvent e){
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if(source == b2){
            checkGuess(l3);
        }else if(source == b3){
            checkGuess(l4);
        }else if(source == b4){
            checkGuess(l5);
        }
        
    }

    private void checkGuess(JLabel label) {
        String inputString = t1.getText().trim();
        try {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(inputString);
            if (number < randomNumber) {
                level--;
                label.setText(String.valueOf(level));
                checkTurns();
                tooLow();
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input! Please enter a valid number.");
        }
    }
    
    private void tooLow(){
        l7.setText("Guess is too low!");
    }

    private void tooHigh(){
        l7.setText("Guess is too high!");
    }

    private void checkTurns(){
        if(level == 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,"OUT OF TURNS!");
            resetFields();
            randomNumber = getRandomNumber();
        }
    } 

    private boolean isNumberOutOfBounds() {
        String input = t1.getText().trim();
        int guess = Integer.parseInt(input);
        return guess >= 0 && guess <= 20;
    }

    private boolean isGuessValidNumber(){
        String input = t1.getText().trim();
        try{
            int guess = Integer.parseInt(input);
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean isInputEmpty(){
        String input = t1.getText().trim();
        return !input.isEmpty();
    }

    private void resetFields(){
        t1.setText("");
        l3.setText("");
        l4.setText("");
        l5.setText("");
        l6.setText("");
        b2.setEnabled(true);
        b3.setEnabled(true);
        b4.setEnabled(true);
        b6.setEnabled(false);
        displayRandomNumber();
    }

    private Color getForeGround(){
        return Color.red;
    }


}
```

Any ideas please?

I've tried just passing a label as a parameter e.g I've passed the hard level label to check guess method and when a wrong guess is entered it decrements the correct label but it won't work unless I pass a label to checkguess();.

```
 private void startingPoint(ActionEvent e){
        if(!isInputEmpty()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,"FIELD CANNOT BE EMPTY!");
        }else if(!isGuessValidNumber()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,"INVALID INPUT! NUMBERS ONLY!");
        }else if(!isNumberOutOfBounds()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f," INVALID NUMBER " + t1.getText() + " IS NOT IN RANGE! ");
        }else{
            checkGuess(l5);
           // checkChoice(e);
        }
    }



 private void checkGuess(JLabel label) {
        String inputString = t1.getText().trim();
        try {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(inputString);
            if (number < randomNumber) {
                level--;
                label.setText(String.valueOf(level));
                checkTurns();
                tooLow();
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input! Please enter a valid number.");
        }
    }


private void checkTurns(){
        if(level == 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,"OUT OF TURNS!");
            resetFields();
            randomNumber = getRandomNumber();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing and hard to understand because of your variable naming conventions. You really want to avoid using trivial variable names such as `l1`, `l2`, `b1`,...  unless they are being used for trivial purposes such as the index of a for loop. Instead use names that have some meaning so that your code becomes self-commenting.

Comment: Also, if your code is not behaving as expected, then it's time to do some debugging, with your IDE's debugger, if possible.

Comment: Why are you extending `JFrame` (which you shouldn't do) and also creating an instance of `JFrame` (which you should do)?  And without a `static main` entry point, how to you run this?

Comment: @WJS that's the way I was thought to do it, there is a static main, its above the imports, there two separate classes.

Comment: @DevoidDude I missed the Gui class.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... The problem I'm having is that the number of guesses label is not decrementing when a wrong guess is entered. ..."*

For the *checkGuess* method, you are only evaluating if *number* is *less-than* *randomNumber*.

```java
int number = Integer.parseInt(inputString);
if (number < randomNumber) {
    level--;
    label.setText(String.valueOf(level));
    checkTurns();
    tooLow();
}
```

Add two more clauses to the *if-structure*.

```java
int number = Integer.parseInt(inputString);
if (number < randomNumber) {
    level--;
    label.setText(String.valueOf(level));
    checkTurns();
    tooLow();
} else if (number > randomNumber) {
                
} else {
                
}
```

Comment: I was gonna fill out the rest of the if statement but I just wanted to test to make sure it would work with numbers less than first to test it was working first.